# Storing a backslash character in Standard ML

Tags: visual-studio-code, sml, backslash, smlnj

I want to store a character '\' in a variable t.

```
val x = #"q";
```

This line leads to a char 'q' in variable x.

Similarly, I tried -

```
val t = #"\\";
```

But this does not work, instead it turns all the code after this line 'orange' (meaning part of a string cause of unclosed ").

From my understanding it turns \" into a char of ", hence the quotes are unclosed.

I am using SML extension in VSCode Editor, although this same problem does not occur when I use an online SML IDE. Can someone explain if this is a problem with the VSCode Extension and what is the way to work around this.

Comment: Those are forward slashes.

Comment: I'm sorry, that was a typo. Edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`val t = #"\\";` is perfectly valid SML. The problem is with the SML extension of VSCode. The simplest workaround in this particular case would be to use

```
val t = chr(92);
```